# Why isn't `system.paxos` being distributed across the cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I have a 11-node Cassandra cluster in a test environment. For some reason, the `system.paxos` table is growing uncontrollably and is not being distributed across the cluster.

`nodetool cfstats` tells me that `paxos` has ~27G of data.

```
Table: paxos
SSTable count: 2406
SSTables in each level: [2400/4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Space used (live), bytes: 28981416094
Space used (total), bytes: 28981416094
```

`du -sh  /data/system/paxos` tells me that one particular node has almost all ~27G of `system.paxos`.

I checked `cassandra.yaml`: the cluster is using the RandomPartitioner, and each node owns about 9% of the space. The other tables are getting distributed as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things in the system keyspace are primarily for internal use and specific for that node. So the keyspace uses a Local only replication strategy:

```
cqlsh:system> describe keyspace system;

CREATE KEYSPACE system WITH replication = {
  'class': 'LocalStrategy'
};
```

2400/4 indicates that of the 4 thats supposed to be in that level theres 2.4k.  There is most definitely something that broke (or so far behind it might as well be). You should check your logs for exceptions, take a stack trace, check compaction stats, and check any monitoring or trending things you have setup. Once collected diagnostic data, restart the node and see if it starts resolving.